# How to find user entered string in array and get position without using if or select?

Tags: java

So I'm teaching myself Java from a book I bought and one of the exercises is to ask the user what kind of item they want and give them the price for the item entered.. I have this set up so far:

```
    String[] flowerName = {"Pentunia", "Pansy", "Rose", "Violet", "Carnation"};
    String[] flowerPrice = {".50", ".75", "1.50", ".50", ".80"};

    System.out.println("What kind of flower would you like?");

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String strFlowerIn = keyboard.next();

    System.out.println("How many would you like?");
    String strFlowerNumIn = keyboard.next();
```

So if the user enters a rose, it asks how many so the result would be:

```
3 Roses = 1.50 * 3 = 4.50
```

How do I take what they entered and compare it the the array to find the index?

Comment: Why can't you use `if` or `select`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without using an if:

```
int index = Arrays.asList(flowerName).indexOf(strFlowerIn);
double price = flowerPrice[index];
double total = price * intFlowerNumIn;
```

You have to change a few things in your code though. This is the complete example:

```
String[] flowerName = {"Pentunia", "Pansy", "Rose", "Violet", "Carnation"};
Double[] flowerPrice = {.50d, .75d, 1.50d, .50d, .80d};

System.out.println("What kind of flower would you like?");

Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
String strFlowerIn = keyboard.nextLine();
int index = Arrays.asList(flowerName).indexOf(strFlowerIn);

System.out.println("How many would you like?");
int intFlowerNumIn = keyboard.nextInt();
decimal price = flowerPrice[index];
decimal total = price * intFlowerNumIn;

System.out.println("Total price: " + total);
```